# Ruby on Rails scopes containing OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

Using OR in ActiveRecord models' scopes can lead to some weird behaviour when these scopes are chained. Assume we have two conditions that we want to disjunctively check, and to also have the scope in which the check occurs be chainable. Given a model with the following scopes:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :test1, lambda { where(SOME_CONDITION).or(SOME_OTHER_CONDITION) }
  scope :test2, lambda { where(id: Test.where(SOME_CONDITION).or(SOME_OTHER_CONDITION)) }
end
```

Then there's a subtle difference between them. The former behaves correctly when called as: `Test.test1`, but if prior to `test1` any other scopes are called, the `or` causes some unintended behaviour, since the prior scopes now only work conjunctively with SOME_CONDITION. Using `test2` fixes this issue, but generates a very hacky looking query, even for the simple case `Test.test2`. Additionally, the latter just looks very hacky. Is there any recommended way to tackle this problem?

Comment: Is "looking hacky" the only concern? If it produces correct results and performance is not worse, then I personally wouldn't care.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The artificial query generated by the second scope, despite behaving correctly, lead me to believe there was a better approach. It creates a query somewhat like: `SELECT _ FROM _ WHERE _.id IN (SELECT id FROM _ WHERE some_condition OR other_condition)`. Where I would actually want it to generate: `SELECT _ FROM _ WHERE some_condition OR other_condition`.

Comment: @engineersmnky That looks like it might work, though I was hoping there would be a way to do this without interfacing with `arel_table`, i.e. by just chaining some scopes. The specific conditions I'm interested in are just: `id IN list` or `other_attribute IN list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the fact that the alternative would likely be to try and determine whether or not conditions already existed (e.g. `where` was already called), which would be even "hackier" (sp?) than the sub-query in my opinion, your best bet is probably to use `Arel` to create the condition.

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :test, -> (val1,val2) {
    where(
      arel_table[:column].in(val1).or(
        arel_table[:column2].in(val2)
      )
    )
  }  
end
```

This option will be order independent when chaining scopes together